# Error while scraping images from website to a folder

Tags: python-2.7

I have started working on python 2 days back and am trying to figure out a pre-existing code for image scraping from website and am stuck with a  "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" error, I'd really appreciate if I can get some assistance on the same.

Comment: please post relevant code and error output

Comment: thanks @code_byter, i managed to figure that error...do u know a way to import mso module...i m getting error which states that mso module could not be found

Comment: I'm sorry, not aware of a module called mso. Are you sure the name is right? Or could you give me a link to the module documentation?

Comment: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/sanand0/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/Office.ipynb...this link has a script which fetches top 250 movies posters and saves them in a folder and then puts those posters in a ppt, i cannot find anyway to download the MSO module specified here. Would be great help if u find it.

Comment: i tried to solve that issue from a post http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/ , but m still getting same error message "ImportError: No module named MSO"

Comment: Please search for this line in that post: `To do this in Python, run Python/Lib/site-packages/win32com/client/makepy.py and pick “Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library” and “Microsoft PowerPoint 12.0 Object Library”. (If you have a version of Office other than 12.0, pick your version.)

This creates two Python files. I rename these files as MSO.py and MSPPT.py`
It means MSO module does not exist. You will have to rename the generated files, and then import them as a module.

Comment: i did the same..to import them i have to write "import MSO" after renaming the generated files right?? or is there any other way to make the generated files as a module...

Comment: The generated files should be in the same directory as the file you are using the `import MSO` line in